# How to initialize a MLMultiArray in CoreML

Tags: swift, ios11, xcode9-beta, coreml, xcode9

I've got an array of 40 arrays with 12 double features, so the type is [[double]]. Currently I'm sending this data to Google Cloud ML API to get a related prediction.

Since Apple recently introduced CoreML and coremltools, I converted my model from keras to .mlmodel to avoid thousand of google cloud api calls and do inference directly on my iPhone:

```
coreml_model = coremltools.converters.keras.convert(new_Model, input_names=['accelerations'],
                                                    output_names=['scores'])
coreml_model.save('PredictionModel.mlmodel')
```

After adding the model to my Xcode Project, it looks like:
[image]

I have no idea, where these others inputs and outputs are comming from.
To get a prediction, I need to convert my Array of Arrays of 12 doubles to an MLMultiArray, but I don't know how to do this. Has anyone faced a similar problem? Here is my current unfinished approach:

```
_predictionModel = PredictionModel()
guard let mlMultiArray = try? MLMultiArray(dataPointer: <#T##UnsafeMutableRawPointer#>, shape: <#T##[NSNumber]#>, dataType: <#T##MLMultiArrayDataType#>, strides: <#T##[NSNumber]#>, deallocator: <#T##((UnsafeMutableRawPointer) -> Void)?##((UnsafeMutableRawPointer) -> Void)?##(UnsafeMutableRawPointer) -> Void#>) else {
        fatalError("Unexpected runtime error.")
    }
guard let predictionOutput = try? _predictionModel.prediction(accelerations: mlMultiArray, lstm_1_h_in: nil, lstm_1_c_in: nil, lstm_2_h_in: nil, lstm_2_c_in: nil) else {
        fatalError("Unexpected runtime error.")
    }
```

The related documentation can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreml/mlmultiarray).

Answer (score 8):

I achieved it by reading this [blog](https://amundtveit.com) :)

```
let data = _currentScaledMotionArrays.reduce([], +) //result is of type [Double] with 480 elements
guard let mlMultiArray = try? MLMultiArray(shape:[40,12], dataType:MLMultiArrayDataType.double) else {
    fatalError("Unexpected runtime error. MLMultiArray")
}
for (index, element) in data.enumerated() {
    mlMultiArray[index] = NSNumber(floatLiteral: element)
}
let input = PredictionModelInput(accelerations: mlMultiArray)
guard let predictionOutput = try? _predictionModel.prediction(input: input) else {
        fatalError("Unexpected runtime error. model.prediction")
}
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem, but I don't know how to start, my input data is an image. So it will be very helpful if anyone how to do it.

Comment: maybe this  [example](https://github.com/yulingtianxia/Core-ML-Sample/blob/master/CoreMLSample/ViewController.swift) could help?

Answer (score 4):

This is how I did it. Probably not the best way to handle optionals but gets the job done for testing

Create an instance of the `MLMultiArray` object with shape and data type

```
let mlArray = try? MLMultiArray(shape: [3], dataType: MLMultiArrayDataType.float32)
```

`mlArray` does not have an append function so you literally have to iterate through it and add values

```
for i in 0..<array.count {
     mlArray?[i] = NSNumber(value: input[i])
}
```

Full function

```
    func convertToMLArray(_ input: [Int]) -> MLMultiArray {

        let mlArray = try? MLMultiArray(shape: [3], dataType: MLMultiArrayDataType.float32)


        for i in 0..<array.count {
            mlArray?[i] = NSNumber(value: input[i])
        }


        return arr!
    }
```