# How copy an NSArray into MLMultiArray in Swift?

Tags: swift, nsarray, plist, coreml

I have an NSArray of size (1, 5, 401) from a plist file. I want to copy that into MLMultiArray of the same shape and then pass it to a CoreML model in **Swift**. How can I copy the values from NSArray to MLMultiArray?

```swift
let filepath = Bundle.main.path(forResource:"testPlist", ofType: "plist")
let dict2 = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: filepath!)

let test_input:NSArray = dict2?.object(forKey:"test_input") as! NSArray

let mlMultiArray_input = try? MLMultiArray (shape:[1,5,401],dataType : MLMultiArrayDataType.double)
```

plist file:
[image]

Comment: `dict2?.object(forKey:"test_input") as! NSArray` Big code smell here (you should not force cast optionals, nor be using "object(forKey)"). You should use Swift native array instead of NSArray. Then you will be able to use the array content easily.

Comment: @EricAya Thank you, but I could not find any code reading a plist array into SwiftUI array.  I added how I read the plist file to the main question. Do you know of a way to read it directly into SwiftUI?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to initialize a MLMultiArray in CoreML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44460532/how-to-initialize-a-mlmultiarray-in-coreml)